# Williams SLLN moral and measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Reading the text below I have two questions :

1) I don't manage to do the exercises : prove that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_{\alpha} = \emptyset$. any help on the proof?

2) If I understand correctly his point, I find it striking that  $P(F_{\alpha})=1$ for all $\alpha$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_{\alpha} = \emptyset$ at the same time.

Is he trying to show how non intuitive is probability? And that we shouldn't rely on intuition for studying it?

At the same time, I think to myself, how is it possible that both of those statements are true !!!! I need your comments about that

[image: David Willimas Probability With Matringales]

Comment: Perhaps intuition comes from a simple problem of throwing darts over the unit interval:   The probability of landing somewhere in particular is 0, but the probability of landing is 1.  That is, let $X$ be uniform over $[0,1]$.  For each $a \in [0,1]$, define $F_a = \{X \neq a\}$.  Then $P[F_a]=1$ for all $a \in [0,1]$, but $\cap_{a \in [0,1]} F_a = \phi$.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very helpful example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Given $\omega$ with infinitely many occurrences of $H$ define $\alpha$ by $\alpha(n) = j$ such that $\omega_j$ is the $n^{th}$ occurrence of $H$. Then, $\# \{k \leq n: \omega_{\alpha(k)}=H\}=n$, by construction. Hence, 
$$\frac{\# \{k \leq n: \omega_{\alpha(k)}=H\}}{n} \to 1 \neq \frac{1}{2}.$$
Thus, $\omega \notin F_\alpha$.

(If $\omega$ has only finitely many occurrences of $H$, then $\omega \notin F_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$.)

We have shown that for *all* $\omega$, there exists *some* $\alpha$ such that $\omega \notin F_\alpha$. It follows that there is *no* $\omega$ that is a member of *every* $F_\alpha$. In other words, $\bigcap_\alpha F_\alpha = \emptyset$.

(2) The reason is that the intersection ranges over *uncountably* many sets. A countable intersection of probability $1$ sets has probability $1$ (you can work this out directly from the definition of a probability measure), but the same needn't hold for uncountable intersections, as this and other examples show. I suppose Williams's point is that there's nothing contradictory about this in a measure-theoretic setting, though I don't really understand the invective about philosophers.

Comment: Yes, the philosopher point is weird, and, is itself written in a pompous way.

Comment: @aduh Thank you for the edit. I hope this is my last question :/ If we set $\alpha^{'}$ as the $\alpha$ you defined by your design, we clearly see that $F_{\alpha^{'}}=\emptyset$ . Now, is $P(F_{\alpha^{'}})=1$ ? If it is, why? If not, why does $P(F_{\alpha})=1$ for all $\alpha$ (Which in my understanding, includes $\alpha^{'}$) hold?

Comment: @aduh It's clear now, I just missed the fact that you defined the $\alpha$ with respect to a specific realisations of $\omega$ and hence the other $\omega$ (infinitely many ones) still make that ratio converge to $\frac{1}{2}$. Thank you though